# 16.04LTS breaks matplotlib in interactive mode

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, matplotlib

Consider the following python code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

plt.ion()
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(1,2)
plt.draw()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

I try this on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16 LTS. I try any conceivable backend, but my plot does not appear. And yes, I am editing the right `matplotlibrc` file.

So I format the disk and reinstall a fresh Ubuntu 14 LTS. The code above works at first try. (I am using the default backend here, I do not even open `matplotlibrc`).

I am doing this both on a dual boot MacBook, and on a Dell Optiplex9020. Same results.

Anybody has a clue what is going on here?

Comment: Couple of questions: 1.) What version of Python are you using `matplotlib` for? 2.) How did you install `matplotlib`?

Comment: To be perfectly fair, on 16.04 some of the backends (TkAgg, Qt5Agg) give me a completely black window. Other backends (agg) give me nothing at all. Many backends raise an error (GTK, GDK) because they want stuff that is not installed.

Comment: `agg` is a non-interactive backend, so it wouldn't give you anything.

Comment: I use the system python that comes with a fresh install. Then I download matplotlib with synaptic. `python --version` gives me 2.7.12 on 16.04. Edit: `which python`gives me `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: So I presume  you installed `python-matplotlib` (as opposed to `python3-matplotlib` which is the Python 3 version)?

Comment: Yep. All of this is in Python 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45547/discussion-between-edwinksl-and-antonio).

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.pause(1)` instead of the last command.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.ion()
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(1,2)

while True:
    plt.pause(1)
```

If you have a for loop with many plots you can use `raw_input()` after `plt.pause(1)`, then the new plot will be shown after you press enter, for example.